# what is media/js folder in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

what is the **`media/js`** folder in Magento 1.9? 
In the w3c validator, it is showing error. How to resolve those errors that are showing in the w3c validator.

Please help

Comment: What is the error you are getting?